# google chart tooltips do not appear on mouseover

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a chart online [here](http://boardlineapp.com/#faq) and when I go over the points with the mouse, I don't see the default tooltips.
Can you help me figure out why ?

Thanks a lot
Here's the code I am using, as you can see I tried to put tooltips manually, but no results...:

```
var dataArray= [ ['Weight', 'Volume \n(Performance)', 'Volume \n(Small-Wave)', 'Volume \n (Step-Up)'] ];
    //var dataArray= [ ['Weight', 'Volume'] ];
    var linearRegX=[];
    var linearRegY=[];
    j=0;
    var tooltipOn = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < prodata.length; ++i) {
            if ( Number(prodata[i]['volume']) !== 0) {
                var tooltipString = prodata[i]['name'] + ' ' + prodata[i]['model'];
                if (prodata[i]['model'] == 'SemiPro12' && prodata[i]['length'] == "6'6" ){  //remove some models
                } else if ( prodata[i]['fun'] == '0') { // performance boards
                linearRegX[j] = Number(prodata[i]['weight']) ;
                linearRegY[j] = Number(prodata[i]['volume']) ;
                if (!tooltipOn){
                    dataArray.push ( [ Number(prodata[i]['weight']), Number(prodata[i]['volume']), null, null ] );
                } else {
                    dataArray.push ( [ Number(prodata[i]['weight']), Number(prodata[i]['volume']), null, null, tooltipString ] );
                }

                j=j+1;
            } else if ( prodata[i]['fun'] == '1') { // small-wave boards
                if (!tooltipOn){
                    dataArray.push ( [ Number(prodata[i]['weight']), null, Number(prodata[i]['volume']), null ] );
                } else {
                    dataArray.push ( [ Number(prodata[i]['weight']), null, Number(prodata[i]['volume']), null, tooltipString ] );
                }                       
            } else if ( prodata[i]['fun'] == '2') { // step-up boards
                if (!tooltipOn){
                    dataArray.push ( [ Number(prodata[i]['weight']), null, null, Number(prodata[i]['volume']) ] );
                } else {
                    dataArray.push ( [ Number(prodata[i]['weight']), null, null, Number(prodata[i]['volume']), tooltipString ] );
                }   

            }
        }
    }
    //option1
    //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    //option2
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //      console.log("dataArray :");
    //      console.log(dataArray);
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Volume \n(Performance)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Volume \n(Small-Wave)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Volume \n(Step-Up)');     
    //adding tooltips (mouseover info)
    if (tooltipOn){
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
    }

    var dataArraySliced = dataArray.slice(1, dataArray.length);
    data.addRows(dataArraySliced);

    var options = {
        title: 'Weight of pro surfer vs. Volume of his pro model',
        hAxis: {title: 'Weight (kg)', minValue: 53, maxValue: 100}, //55
        vAxis: {title: 'Volume (l)'}, //, minValue: 20, maxValue: 40},   //20
        legend: 'none',
           width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
           colors: ['#000000'],
           series: {
                  1: { color: '#06b4c8' }, 
                  2: { color: '#575e6a' }
              },
        legend: {position: 'top right', textStyle: {fontSize: 8}},
        chartArea: {width: '60%'},
           trendlines: { 0: {//type: 'exponential',
                    visibleInLegend: true,
                    color: 'grey',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    opacity: 0.2,
                    labelInLegend: 'Linear trendline\n(Performance)'
                    } 
                }    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));        
    chart.draw(data, options);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', myReadyHandler());
```

Comment: Update your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and any steps you have already attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: @asgallant, I just did it. Can you please vote it back up ? Thanks

Comment: Can you update with an example of `prodata` so I can test this?

Comment: Nevermind, I pulled it off your site.

Comment: Thanks I see you've pulled the data. I think the fact that the charts dimensions are not right comes from the fact that I change the dimensions of its container in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your chart on jsfiddle, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/j3778edd/.  The only issue I see is that you call `myReadyHandler` and pass its return value (probably `null`) in the "ready" event listener instead of passing the function itself:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', myReadyHandler());
```

should be:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', myReadyHandler);
```

which, while technically incorrect, is not likely to be the culprit for your problems.

My test results also do not have the same dimension issues as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25539134/613559).  There is probably some CSS or javascript elsewhere in your code that is interfering with the chart.  I suggest starting the process of figuring this out by disabling all of your javascript and css that is not strictly necessary for the chart to draw.  If the problem persists, then it is likely in your chart code; if it goes away, then it is elsewhere.  If, as I suspect, it lies elsewhere, try enabling the rest of your code piece by piece until the chart breaks - when that happens, you've found the likely culprit.

Comment: I removed the chart div out of its container, whose I was manipulating the size and position with jquery....and now it works. Don't ask me why ;-)

Comment: You were probably changing the size and position after drawing the chart, which would cause issues like those you saw.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I couldn't see the tooltips anymore and I could not figure out why. That's how I ended up here. I found my problem, totally unrelated to the answers above. It had to do with the z-index style. This is what I had:

```
<div google-chart chart="chart_summary" style="height: 400px; top: -50px; z-index:-998;" on-ready="chartReady()"></div>
```

I had changed the z-index value to test something else and forgot about it. Because the value was so low, it was basically behind something else (transparent) that covered it an prevented the mouseover event to be triggered.

So, if you changed the z-index, (css may change it too), then it might be that your graph is hidden by some transparent object whose z-index is higher than your graph. One easy test to do would be to give it a very high z-index and see if you still have the issue.

```
<div google-chart chart="chart_summary" style="height: 400px; top: -50px; z-index:1000000;" on-ready="chartReady()"></div>
```